# Problem sending data to other activity in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I want to send data from three activities to the last activity, how can I do

**1. First Activity**

```
else {
//first activity want transfer data last activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Register.this, Register2.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", reg_name);
        intent.putExtra("surname", reg_surname);
        intent.putExtra("email", reg_email);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**2. Second Activity**

```
else {
//second activity transfer data last activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(Register2.this, PhoneNumberOtp.class);
        intent.putExtra("username", reg_username);
        intent.putExtra("password", reg_password);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**3. Third Activity**

```
 else {
//third activity transfer data last activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(PhoneNumberOtp.this, OTPVerification.class);
        intent.putExtra("phoneNumber", reg_phone_number);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

**Last Activity**

```
else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(OTPVerification.this, HomeActivity.class);
        //get data register activity
        String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        String surname = getIntent().getExtras().getString("surname");
        String email = getIntent().getExtras().getString("email");
        String username = getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");
        String password = getIntent().getExtras().getString("password");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extras you put on an intent are not automatically passed along to subsequent activities after the first one they are sent to directly. If you have some data you want to pass through multiple activities, you have to re-add it to the new sending intent for each step. For example:

**First**

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(UserActivity.this, AccountActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("name", reg_name);
intent.putExtra("email", reg_email);
startActivity(intent);
```

**Second**

```java
Intent intent = new Intent(AccountActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);

// get the received data and add it to the new intent
Intent recv = getIntent();
if( recv != null ) {
    String name = recv.getStringExtra("name");
    intent.putExtra("name", name);

    String email = recv.getStringExtra("email");
    intent.putExtra("email", email);
}

// then add any new data
intent.putExtra("username", reg_username);
intent.putExtra("password", reg_password);

startActivity(intent);
```

**Third**

```java
// RegisterActivity now has 4 strings available
Intent recv = getIntent();
if( recv != null ) {
    String name = recv.getStringExtra("name");
    String email = recv.getStringExtra("email");
    String username = recv.getStringExtra("username");
    String password = recv.getStringExtra("password");
}
```

In the example you posted, the last activity would only have access to `phoneNumber`, since that's all you passed it from the third activity.